# Integrate SquareSpace site to third party database site

Tags: database, integration, squarespace, stripe-connect

I have a client that is using a third party custom membership database for a an online service that currently collects member data and payment information.  They recently switched their landing page to Squarespace where non-members can find out more about their service and then they are forwarded over to the database site.  My clients would like to use the eCommerce option on the Squarespace website, so my question would be does anyone know of how to integrate payment and membership information to be directed from Stripe or SquareSpace to a third party membership database?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Squarespace doesn't offer the ability to "call out" to any 3rd party services, server-side.

Having said that, I see three ways to accomplish this.

1. Use client-side Javascript [injected into the Order Confirmation
   Page](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205815908-Using-Code-Injection). That means that the server on the receiving end would have
   to have CORS support (allowing such a request to come from your
   Squarespace site) or it would either have to provide its own API or
   support JSONP.
2. Use some type of service to parse the email that you receive when an order is made. When an order is placed, users of your Squarespace site with admin or store-manager permissions will receive an email. If you have a service that can "watch" for this type of email to come in (or run every X minutes) it is possible to parse the email and then take some kind of action as a result. One drawback here is that Squarespace doesn't allow much customization to emails, so if Squarespace heavily modifies the format of the email, it could break your service. [Zapier](https://zapier.com/) is a service that might help you accomplish this approach.
3. Because any activity from your Squarespace "store" will generate activity within your Stripe account, it may be possible to use [Stripe's Events/Webhooks service](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) to call out to your database service. I have not attempted this, but it is something that may be possible.

Of course, these all assume that there is an "endpoint" URL associated with your membership database that can receive the data and handle it accordingly.

Comment: Awesome thanks Brandon.  I'm going to look into all of these